# Linking Parse in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, brackets

New to coding! I have an iOS app successfully connected to my Parse/AWS backend and now trying to connect a webpage I am creating in Brackets to it but I get errors in Brackets?? Is there code I am missing or additional set-up required??
Below is my set-up code..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"><script>
     <title>Website Title</title>
</head>

// JS FILE

Parse.initialize("myappID", "Client_Key");
Parse.serverURL = "LINK-TO-My-INSTANCE"
```

Comment: What's the error that you have? And when do you see this error?